# Pretty Faces multiple annotation, which one was loaded?

Tags: jsf-2, url-routing, prettyfaces

I have a multiple PrettyFaces annotation on a Managed Bean, how do I determine from which entry point the page was loaded without looking at parameters passed ?

```
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLAction;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMappings;

@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
    @ViewScoped
    @URLMappings(mappings = {
            @URLMapping(id = "addObject", pattern = "add/type-#{bean.type}", viewId = "/views/object.jsf" ),
            @URLMapping(id = "editObject", pattern = "edit/#{bean.objId}", viewId = "/views/object.jsf")
    })
    public class Bean implements Serializable { 
        private Long type;
        private Long objId;

        @URLAction(onPostback = false)
        public void load() {
                if(objId!=null){
                    //edit mode
                }else{
                    // add mode
                }
        }       
        // getters / setters
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the ID of the *current mapping* usind the `PrettyContext` like this:

```
String id = PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentMapping().getId();
```